# How to select records which don't exist in another table or have a different status?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select records from a temp table based on another temp table which holds their previous statuses (`StatusHistory`).

So if the record doesn't exist in the status table, then it should be selected. If the status of the record is different than the one in the `StatusHistory` table, then the record should be selected. Otherwise, if it exists with the same status in the `StatusHistory` table, then it should be ignored.

I have this SQL but it doesn't seem to be the best solution. Can you please point me to a better way to achieve that assuming that there are thousands of records in the tables? Would it be possible to achieve the same result with a JOIN statement?

```
SELECT  AI.item
FROM #AllItems AI
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
        SELECT * FROM #StatusHistory HS
           WHERE HS.itemId = AI.itemId
                 ) OR NOT AI.itemStatus IN ( SELECT HS.itemStatusHistory
                                             FROM #StatusHistory HS
                                             WHERE HS.itemId = AI.itemId 
                                             AND HS.itemId = AI.itemId )
```

Comment: What if it exists in the status history table with the same status *and* a different status?

Comment: @AaronBertrand it will only exist once in the table. The idea is that later on, I am going to update it with the new status.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with a LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT AI.item
FROM #AllItems AI
    LEFT JOIN #StatusHistory HS ON AI.itemId = HS.itemId
        AND AI.itemStatus = HS.itemStatusHistory
WHERE HS.itemId IS NULL
```

A better solution, however, is to use NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT AI.item
FROM #AllItems AI
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM #StatusHistory SH
   WHERE SH.itemId = AI.itemId
       AND SH.itemStatusHistory = AI.itemStatus
);
```

As pointed out by Aaron, [this usually performs better than a LEFT JOIN](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join).

Comment: Yes.  Whenever the criteria include "doesn't exist in another table", you should right away think "outer join".

Comment: [This doesn't seem to match the results of the OP's query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3099f/4).

Comment: Note that this doesn't need to use an OUTER JOIN; the [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3099f/4) I created also demonstrates a NOT EXISTS variation. Sometimes [this choice can matter](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join).

Comment: You should probably put that as an answer, as it's a better solution.

Comment: Or you could just add it to your answer/

Comment: Great answers and a nice link! I'll accept the answer later, hopefully you'll add it in any of the answers.